# Clicking radiobutton on first web page opens new window. Finding issues with filling form on second window

Tags: python, selenium

I have a web page (already created) that when clicked on one of the radiobuttons, opens a new window. On this new window, I have to select some options from it and click on "Finished" on this second window which will close the second window and take me to the first window where I can click on Submit and a report will be shown to me. I have to do this many times and want to automate this. My code is in Python and I am using Selenium. However, I am finding difficulty in the second window to either fill out the form or even to click a button. I am trying to put as much code of the first and second window as possible. Also putting my python code.

thank you in advance for your help.

First window code: application_form.asp

```
    <BODY ...>
       <TABLE ...>
          <FORM METHOD='POST' ACTION="application_report.asp">
             <TABLE ...>
                <TR>
                   <TD>
                      <p><input type="radio" value="Pick" name="Choice" id="p3"
                         onclick=javascript:LaunchPopup('MFList.asp','MFLpars','width=750,scrollbars=yes')>
                         <label for="p3">Select lpars />
                      </p>
                      <p><textarea name="Selected"></textarea>
                      </p>
    ...
    ...
```

Second window code: MFList.asp

```
<BODY>
   <FORM METHOD="POST" name="Form">
      <td class="label">
         <select name="all_fields">
            <option VALUE="ABCD">ABCD(ABCD)</option>
            <option VALUE="PQRS">PQRS(PQRS)</option>
         </select>
         <td class="label">
            <button onclick="menu(this.form,this.form.all_fields,this.form.fields)"> &gt;&gt;&gt;</button>
            <br />
            <button onclick="menu(this.form,this.form.fields,this.form.all_fields)"> &lt;&lt;&lt;</button>
         <td class="label"><p><select name="fields">
         <option value="NULL">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
         </select>
         </p>
         </td>
         </table>

<p> <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Finished" name="button" onClick="LparBack(this.form) SUBMIT>&nbsp;
<INPUT type="hidden" name="_ABCD" value="ABCD">
<INPUT type="hidden" name="_PQRS" value="PQRS">
<INPUT type="hidden" name="" value="picked">

      </FORM>
```

My Python code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe location')
driver.get('first page url.asp')
time.sleep(3)
radio_butn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#p3").click()
time.sleep(3)

#Until above all code works. It clicks on radio button and opens new window
#Now below what I want is to click on at least one option from left and select it to the right and then #click on "Finished" button. However, I am struggling to even click on "Finished" button itself. 

window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to.window(window_after)
fin_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#button").click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.quit()
```

if you want to see the second window, I have uploaded it at: (hope it viewable by everybody).
https://ibb.co/b3zhC8m

Thanks.

Comment: after your driver.get() call, get current window handle.  (driver.window_handle).  Then after the new window is opened, get all window handles (driver.window_handles).  Iterate through and use the handle that is not the current.  (Don't rely on array to be in a specific order.)

Comment: I added this code before the code to click on radiobutton:
window_before = driver.current_window_handle

and this code after the new window opens:
cnt = len(driver.window_handles)
for x in range(cnt):
    if driver.window_handles[x] != window_before:
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[x])

Still the same error comes:
Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input#button"}

Comment: I believe "#" is for id.  Try with input[name='button']

Comment: wow. thank you @pcalkins. at least this time no error came. I used find_element_by_name("button").click() and the window did get closed. 

Now, my next goal is to select one of the options (in the example above ABCD) so that it looks selected. let me try.

Comment: now this code also works;

el = driver.find_element_by_name('all_fields')
for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == 'ABCD':
        option.click()
        break